# Apply a function to multiple columns in R

Tags: r, dataframe, function, apply

I have the following problem
How to apply the function `dmy` only to those columns of my dataframe `df`, which contain `"Date"`?

```
x  Cat  Date1        y   AnotherDate
1  as   31.12.2020   56  04.04.2004
2  ab   31.12.2019   78  05.09.2010
3  bs   30.09.2021   26  25.11.2012
4  bd   20.08.2021   33  31.01.2022
```

If I want to apply the function to all columns of dataframe, the code is the following:

```
library(lubridate)
apply(df, 2, dmy)
```

This causes an error, because `dmy` is not applicable to all columns.
How to transform this code, to apply `dmy` not to all of the columns, but only to columns, which contain the word "Date" inside their name?

Additional question: can I also use regular expressions in choosing column names inside the apply function? How to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the `dplyr` package to apply a function to several columns:

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

df %>%
  mutate(across(matches("Date"), dmy))
```

Alternatively, you can use `apply` but you have to select the relevant columns first. This can be done using `grep`:

```
df[, grep("Date", colnames(df))] <- apply(df[, grep("Date", colnames(df))], 2, dmy)
```